# Take specific item of the table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-traversal

I am with the following function:

```
$ ("# GridView1 tr"). Click (function (e){

                 var $ cell = $ (e.target). closest ("td");
                 $ ("# TextBox3"). Val ($ cell.text ())
   }
```

What makes the TextBox3 receive the value of clicked square on the table, what I needed was to get a specific value of the same row of the table by clicking on any square in that row. You can do this?

Comment: Are you sure you have all those strange spaces in your code?

Comment: Sorry guys, I edited the question, not realising that the original syntax could be the source of the problem!

Comment: @adarshr: Then do a rollback ;)

Comment: @Felix: You sure you can tolerate to see jQuery being written like that? :)

Comment: @adarshr: Actually I have seen worse ;) :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your jQuery event targets the `tr` element, code inside the event callback will have `this` assigned to that element's DOM object by default. You can use that to find any of its children (any of the cells in the row).

```
$('#GridView1 tr').click(function() {
    /**
     * You can grab the `td` you want by specifying its index or using a
     * class selector.
     */
    var desired_cell_index = 5;
    var desired_cell = $(this).find('td').eq(desired_cell_index);

    $('#TextBox3').val(cell_data.text());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This will first find the closest table row, and inside that, will look for a specific cell (you were not giving any details on that one, so I used the class `specific` here).

```
 var $cell = $(e.target).closest ("tr").find('td.specific');
```